# Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: number is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I started working on small project using Laravel and Vue.js. I tried to use `v-model` to set a value, but I get an error as seen below:

```html
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="edit" v-model="number = 1">
  <i class="icon-file-text2"></i> Modifier
</a>
```

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    searchInput: '',
    buildings: {},
    number: null
  }
}
```

Error message that I get:

```
Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: number is not defined"
```

Comment: Why didn't change the variable name from Number to any expressive variable name like Num or count NoOfItems? many errors come from using reserved keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-model` takes the name of a local data prop, so you should not use an expression there. However, `v-model` only makes sense for user input elements (e.g., `<input>`, `<select>`, etc.), not for readonly elements, such as `<a>`.

If you intended to set `number` to `1` upon clicking `<a>`, I recommend moving that code into the `edit()` method already bound to the `click`-event:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    edit() {
      this.number = 1
    }
  }
}
```